# Golang Simulate Page Visit : Surf Not Triggering Javascript

Tags: go, web-scraping, emulation

I have a Go program that is just simulating a local web page being visited using Surf (`gopkg.in/headzoo/surf.v1`) but it seems that the Javascript on the page is not being executed. Just to test I have the web page doing an ajax call to another route on the server that will just output a response on the server side.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.ajax ({
    url : "/test",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(res) {},
    error : function(res) {}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the Go Surf function to visit the page, this route also outputs a response on the server side which is showing up but the one from the ajax request is not showing up.

```
func simulateVisit() {

    bow := surf.NewBrowser()
    bow.SetUserAgent("LocalCrawler/1.0")

    err := bow.Open("http://127.0.0.1/page")
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err) }

}
```

To make sure it is only happening from Surf I also tested it with Chromedp (`github.com/chromedp/chromedp`) which gave both responses correctly.

Is this a limitation with Surf or am I doing something silly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surf does not include a JS runtime. It does support the downloading of [scripts](https://github.com/headzoo/surf/blob/37385ffec513af0627ee55d8d13b7bb890bb1bc0/browser/assets.go#L188), but it will never actually execute them.

Comment: Bugger, that's a bit disappointing but that you so much

Comment: I don't suppose you know of an alternative to Surf that has a JS runtime? That would be pretty amazing

Comment: No sorry, the only JS runtime implemented in go that I know of is https://github.com/dop251/goja. But I think nobody has taken on the challenge of combining a scraper and a JS runtime. Likely because you would have to implement web API's and thus 3/4's of a browser. chromedp is your best shot to get anything like it AFAIK